# OpenGL context without a monitor

Tags: opengl, glfw, glad

I want to create an opengl context but that context must be created without a monitor attach to the system. The reason I want this is because this program should ran in a linux ubuntu server. Inside a docker image to be specific. I'm using many opengl libraries including modern opengl(GLSL), GLFW, glad and glm. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482166/creating-opengl-context-without-window) but I'm not sure whether or not one of the methods will work and it might be a bit outdated. I've also seen someone using something like this on an obsolete site but I'm not sure how to implement it:

```
glXMakeContextCurrent(display,None,None,context);
```

I think it still needs a window as `display`, if not what is the type of `display` and `context` variable and where can i download glX?

Edit: I'm only using GLFW for window/context creation on my local machine so I can exclude it.

Comment: I'm somewhat sure you can emulate presence of a display via some Linux commands

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov How can I emulate one? Can you put me on the right track please?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I've tried running `apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy` but its stuck at "Choose a country for keyboard layout" question, I answer it but when I press enter nothing happens. What should i do?

Comment: I've never used it myself, but there is [xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb#:~:text=Xvfb%20or%20X%20virtual%20framebuffer,without%20showing%20any%20screen%20output.). Should be possible to install with `sudo apt-get install xvfb` and use for your application executable via `xvfb-run -a "your command"`

Comment: That worked! Can you post it as an answer so i can accept is pelase?

Comment: You could also look at EGL, which is designed for this purpose and for this reason, and will probably replace GLX in the future (e.g. Wayland uses EGL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [X Virtual Framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb#:%7E:text=Xvfb%20or%20X%20virtual%20framebuffer,without%20showing%20any%20screen%20output.) that allows to emulate presence of a physical display in Linux.

It can be installed via

```
apt-get install xvfb
```

And used as

```
xvfb-run -a "your command"
```